# Ubuntu fails to boot after kubuntu-desktop uninstalled

Tags: unity, kubuntu, kde

Some time ago I installed kubuntu-desktop on my Ubuntu 14.04 using these [instructions](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/kde).

However, after some time I noticed that my Eclipse started crashing often under KDE so I decided to remove it. I followed the following [instructions](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu).

Unfortunately, not all of the components could be removed, some of them were reported as non-existent. It wasn't until then that I noticed these instructions were for Ubuntu 12.10, whereas mine is 14.04, so I tried to google the answer and ended up executing several commands from the Internet, the reference to which I don't even remember (yeah, now I realize how stupid it was to blindly run all I found online in my terminal...).

Finally I followed this [advice](https://askubuntu.com/a/483592/292579).

I was shocked when after executing the `sudo apt-get autoremove` I saw that multiple Linux images were removed. I was worried about the stability of my system, so I tried reinstalling Unity. I saw that it created some system image so I got calmed down.

However, when I tried rebooting my computer, the loading screen displays 'Kubuntu 14.04' (whereas before "removing" Kubuntu, when kubuntu-desktop and unity were installed, it always showed 'Ubuntu 14.04') and this is what is displayed next:

[image]

It then shows a few possible modes of running, i.e. low-graphics mode, troubleshooting etc. Unfortunately, none of them results in anything else than an infinite black screen...

Is there any chance of repairing the system? I would really like to avoid reinstalling and reconfiguring it.

I tried to solve my problem by following the instructions under the suggested link. I didn’t manage to load failsafeX, but I did enter the terminal with ctrl – alt – f1.

I checked my version of the graphics card and it is NVIDIA Corporation G98 [Quadro NVS 295] (rev a1). I then reinstalled the drivers using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`. I also reinstalled unity with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`.

After rebooting I saw the Ubuntu loading screen but the same error message appeared afterwards. I entered the terminal again and typed `startx`. What happened next is that the desktop wallpaper appeared and my autostart programs began to load up. However, there was no side-bar or the upper panel. I also couldn’t switch between programs using alt – f4.

I then tried executing some more commands, the results of which are presented below.

It seems to me that the graphics card somehow doesn’t recognize the monitor that is hooked up.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Regarding eclipse crashes: were you using `oxygen-gtk`?

Comment: In the end I didn't manage to fix this problem and had to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you post it as an answer and accept it, please? This will save some time for those who are searching for an unsolved question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I didn't manage to fix this problem and had to reinstall Ubuntu.